# Make Mouse Click Entire Area Instead of Point

Tags: click, action, mouse, point, area

I am having an online course that is very boring. In the virtual application i have to read hundreds of pages and in each of them i have to press a button to go to next page. This buttons appear in random areas of the application windows. I'm trying to see a way that when i press the mouse click button, instead of clicking in the point where the mouse is, it will perform the click action in every element that is in a specifc area of the mouse position at that time. I don't   know if such feature is even possible but i wish you guys could give me any help on it.

I would like to let the mouse in the middle of the application screen and then set the windows size as the area i want to perform the click action. after that i could record mouse action to click every 4 seconds and that is it. That will make my day brighter again !

I thanks everyone for the attention and have a good day.

Comment: potentially interesting, but it lacks details. E.g. are you a programmer? Do you have exact screenshots of that button to show us? It might be as well marked as off-topic if you just seek for a complete solution or coding service.

Comment: As for the question - yes one can perform automated clicks in various ways, but I'd say if do it like that (repeat a click on points of the area) something bad will happen, if there is something else there after the first click, and the system may change its state completely.